# C# - ScrollBar snapping back to original position when dragging too far

Tags: c#, .net, scrollbar, controls

C# - .Net4.0, Visual Studio 2010

Despite hearing how much of a pain they are, I'm using a VScrollBar object with a custom control I'm creating. Whilst fiddling around with it I noticed that whilst you're dragging the scrollbar's "thumb", if the mouse is moved so far down past the control it's attached to, the "thumb" jumps back to its original position. It wouldn't be such a problem, but the distance you can drag it down makes it fiddly if you just want to scroll to the bottom of a page. This happens if you do the same in the opposite direction (***and*** happens with HScrollBar too), and I'd like to know if there's any way of stopping this whilst still using, or inheriting from this kind of control.

I can't seem to find any attributes or methods to do with this on the MSDN, and I can't find a great deal elsewhere. I'm not completely married to using VScrollBar, but I would prefer to, especially if the alternative is to inherit my custom control from anything other than the base Control class.

Comment: Just set the AutoScrollMinSize of a Panel control to get a vertical scroll bar.

Comment: Thanks, but not really applicable to my problem. Like I say, would prefer to figure it out with VScrollBar, or even just create a custom scrollbar from scratch if necessary. Sounds like I might end up doing the latter.

Comment: ...Also I've just messed around with panels a bit. They show the same kind of snapping behavior, so doesn't solve anything. =/